# Critical values of the restriction

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

Let $g:(x,y,z,w)\mapsto x^2+y^2+z^2-w^2$. Then by the regular value theorem, the set $g^{-1}(-1)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$ of codimension 1.

The question is, if $f:(x,y,z,w)\mapsto w$, then what are the critical values of the restricted map $f|_{g^{-1}(-1)}$?

The map $f$ has the Jacobian $[0,0,0,1]$, so is it not of full rank everywhere (hence no critical value of the restriction)?

What if the map was $f:(x,y,z,w)\mapsto w^2$? In that case, the Jacobian fails to be of full rank precisely when $w=0$. But $g^{-1}(-1)$ has no point where $w=0$, hence no critical value here as well?

Answer (score 1):

it is  a hyperboloid of two sheets. There are two critical points of  your $w$ which occur when $w = \pm 1$  and $x=y=z=0$

[image]

Comment: Is this for the case when the map is $f:(x,y,z,w)\mapsto w^2$?

Comment: @user134070 I added a picture, which is a slice when two out of the three $x,y,z$ are zero

Comment: Thank you. I know that the sets where $x=y=z=0$ and $w=\pm 1$ is a hypoerbolid. I just am not sure how you got it.